# Expose mongo port in other container

Tags: mongodb, docker, ssh-tunnel, docker-image

I have this (custom) container which runs a java program which requires mongo locally. Now, with docker I would like to setup mongo in its own container. So I guess, in order to expose this 27017 port locally in this java-container I need to setup an SSH-tunnel, right ? If there is a easier way please let me know.

So, there is this official [mongo image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) image, but I get the impression `ssh` is not install or running. What would be the best approach to do this?

UPDATE: I've rephrased the question more focussed on port-forwarding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633057/ssh-port-forwarding-in-docker)

Answer (score 6):

You have to make your container run on the same network. No need to ssh into your mongo or app container.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

First define a network

```
docker network create --driver bridge isolated_nw
```

Start you containers using that newly network

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 --network=isolated_nw -itd --name=mongo-cont mongo
docker run --network=isolated_nw -itd --name=app your_image
```

The image of mongo includes EXPOSE 27017 so from your app container, you should be able to access to the mongo container using its name `mongo-cont`

Comment: the java application accesses the db as `localhost:27017`, so I guess that you solutions doesn't wok, right ?

Comment: Edited my answer to open port

Comment: Also as mentionned you can't use localhost:27017 but you have to use mongo-cont:27017

Comment: At the moment I cannot change the java configuration, so I cannot change `localhost:27017` to `mongo-cont:27017` which is why I was looking at SSH port mapping

Answer (score 4):

You can build your custom image on top of mongodb official image, which gives you the flexibility to install additional required packages.

```
FROM mongo:latest
RUN apt-get install ssh
```

Also try to use `docker-compose` to build and link your containers together, it will ease the process greatly.

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017"

  custom_project:
    build:
      context: .  # Parent directory address of Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-Custom  # Name of Dockerfile
    command: /root/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

[This](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/4d7bd01562edefad38a240c40a4b162a1cd7b9c2/3.2/Dockerfile) is the image used for mongodb official image.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to SSH **into your container** to gain access to it, but that isn't how you connect. Docker provides functionality to securely connect via the following methods.

Connect into a running container - [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/):

```
docker exec -it <container name> bash
$ root@665b4a1e17b6:/#
```

Start a container from image, and connect to it - [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/):

```
docker run -it <image name> bash
$ root@665b4a1e17b6:/#
```

Note: If it is an **Alpine** based image, it may not have Bash installed. In that case using `sh` instead of `bash` in your commands should work. Mongo's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/4d7bd01562edefad38a240c40a4b162a1cd7b9c2/3.2/Dockerfile) looks to use `debian:jessie` which will have `bash` support.

Comment: I need to map the db port to the java container such that the java application can access the db as `localhost:27017`