# SSH port forwarding in Docker

Tags: ssh, docker, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have these two containers, say `backend` (CentOs) and `mongo`. What I would like to have is that from within the `backend` container I can connect to the mongo database as if it was running locally, `$> mongo localhost:27017`

Anyway, as far as I understand all this, you can map the port localhost:27017 to mongo:27017 like this

```
$backend> ssh -L 27017:mongo:27017 root@mongo
```

However, if I do this I have to provide the root password and after that it logs me into the `mongo` container and no port forwarding is happening

Background: I want to do this because I'm running a Java program which connects to a Mongo database on localhost and I cannot change that.

Comment: Are you using a native linux host or something like docker machine? Do you have any error message when running your `ssh -L` command?

Comment: I'm using `docker-compose`. I can `ssh` from the `backend` to `mongo`. Its on a Mac so I guess its still `docker-machine` somewhere

Comment: Have you seen this ? https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#/communication-between-containers

Comment: I've added a couple examples of what I've tried and what the outcome was. Furthermore, I think this problem has not to do with docker, but with me not understanding SSH port forwarding

Comment: @Jeanluca: we don't use [solved] title hacks here. Please just accept the answer below that most corresponds to your solution (including your own).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the correct SSH port forwarding command

```
$> ssh root@mongo -L 27017:localhost:27017 -Nf
```

Normally the idea with this command is that you map a non-public port - through a public server to you own server/compute.

```
* `root@mongo` - the public server
* -L <port on your server>:<third server address>:<port>
* `-Nf` - Do not login
```

Because the `public server` and `third server` are the same computer/container you have to use `localhost` :)

Comment: I don't get it. Doesn't this forward the port INTO the container? what exports from the container?