# Publish port on localhost of another container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have following docker-compose.yml (left out not essential parts):

```
zabbix-server:
  image: zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql:alpine-4.0-latest
  ports:
   - "10051:10051"
  networks:
   zbx_net_backend:
     aliases:
      - zabbix-server
zabbix-agent:
  image: zabbix/zabbix-agent:alpine-4.0-latest
  ports:
   - "10050:10050"
  networks:
   zbx_net_backend:
    aliases:
     - zabbix-agent
networks:
  zbx_net_backend:
    driver: bridge
    internal: true
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.16.239.0/24
```

The *zabbix-server* is looking out-of-the-box for the *zabbix-agent* on its `localhost:10050`. Is it possible to make the port 10050 of the *zabbix-agent* available on localhost:10050 of the *zabbix-server*?

I know that I can configure the zabbix-agent hostname in the zabbix-server via `"Configuration" -> "Hosts" -> edit -> "DNS Name"` but I want to avoid that if possible and achieve it via configuration of the docker-compose.yml.

Comment: If this is a dev setup, best practice is to remove all of the network configuration, make the target address configurable via an env variable (e.g. `AGENT_URL`), and set `AGENT_URL=zabbix-agent/`. Services can target each other by using the service name as an URL

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633057/ssh-port-forwarding-in-docker

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make the target address configurable where it is used (maybe it already is?) and set the target to be the relevant docker compose service:

```
zabbix-server:
  image: zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql:alpine-4.0-latest
  environment:
    AGENT_URL: zabbix-agent
  ports:
   - "10051:10051"

zabbix-agent:
  image: zabbix/zabbix-agent:alpine-4.0-latest
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to redirect the `localhost` loopback device point to another container. But, if you really want this, then you can connect them both to the `host` network.

**Like this:**

```
zabbix-server:
  image: zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql:alpine-4.0-latest
  ports:
   - "10051:10051"
  network_mode: "host"
zabbix-agent:
  image: zabbix/zabbix-agent:alpine-4.0-latest
  ports:
   - "10050:10050"
  network_mode: "host"
```

Doing this, will allow you to address the zabbix-agent with `localhost:10050` from the zabbix-server container.